# How to use conditional statements when overriding toString

Tags: scala, conditional-operator

I'm trying to override toString using conditional statements. But I'm getting an error that says there is a type mismatch. It is supposed to be in String type and right now it's in Any type.
noGoals, Tied are functions that returns true or false.

```
override def toString = {
  if (this.noGoals)
    s"${this.home} vs. ${this.away} at ${this.location}: no goals"
  else if (this.Tied)
    s"${this.home} vs. ${this.away} at ${this.location}: tied"
}
```

Comment: Not directly relevant, but I don't feel good about putting behavioral logic in `toString()`. It is supposed to represent a human readable view of the object not implement a lot of logic. It's possibly better to use another method to display info to the user.

Comment: Hint: what string do you return when both of those conditions are false?

Answer (score 6):

The expression

```
if (conditionA) "aa"
else if (conditionB) "bb"
```

defaults to

```
if (conditionA) "aa"        
else if (conditionB) "bb"   
else ()                     // oops () types to Unit
```

where value `()` has `Unit` type, whilst values `"aa"` and `"bb"` have type `String`, and least upper bound of `Unit` and `String` is `Any`. Thus try providing default string to the last else branch like so

```
if (conditionA) "aa"
else if (conditionB) "bb"
else "default"
```